# compare and fetch unique data, stored in comma separation

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database where error_code and error_type are stored.

Each Error_type can have multiple error_code stored as comma separation.

Here is a table

id  error_code     error_type

1   300,200,444    spelling

2       333,310            grammer

As shown ; spelling has 3 error_code

Question: how to query to get error_type if error_code is only 300 or 200 or 444 (only 1 error code will be entered in text box)

let me know if any info needed or if am not clear .... tnx

EDIT:

I need a distinct error_type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regexp:

```
select * from test
where error_code REGEXP '(^444,|,444$|,444,|^444$)'
```

This will ensure that `444` is present either at the beginning, at the end, or in between of two commas; it would *not* match strings where `444` is inside another number. For example, `1,2,34445,6` will not be matched.

Comment: your code will not fetch distinct error_type, if i enter 3 , it fetches other category whos code is 3 something.. :(

Comment: @sree I modified the answer to avoid this. The regexp became more complex, but it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `like`

```
select error_type from table where error_code like '%300%'
```

or

```
select error_type from table where error_code like '%444%'
```

Comment: This will match even if `error_code` is `123444`, which is probably not what the OP wanted.

Comment: clearly if it was that easy.... :)   also its "error_code like"... am correcting ur answer